# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error raised in the SELECT statement

Tags: oracle

```
(
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
    FROM   WTH
    WHERE  objstate IN ('Closed')
    AND    actual_date_finished > Sysdate -30
    AND    Trunc(requested_date_finished) = trunc(actual_date_finished)
    AND    contract LIKE NVL('$SITE$','%')
  )/(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   WTH
    WHERE  objstate IN ('Closed')
    AND    actual_date_finished > Sysdate -30
    AND    contract LIKE NVL('$SITE$','%')
  ) * 100
)
```

Comment: What are you using to run this query? It is not valid SQL on its own as there are two separate statements here.

Comment: I presume you want to wrap this between 'SELECT' and 'FROM DUAL'. You don't need the outermost brackets. What will happen if the second count returns 0?

Comment: SO is all about asking a question and getting an answer that hopefully solves your problem and helps others in the process. You should therefore frame your issue as a question that people can understand.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it all in a single SQL statement:

```
SELECT CASE
         COUNT(*)
         WHEN 0      -- Handle division by zero
         THEN NULL
         ELSE COUNT(
                CASE
                  WHEN TRUNC(requested_date_finished) = trunc(actual_date_finished)
                  THEN 1
                END
              )
              / COUNT(*)
              * 100
       END
FROM   WTH
WHERE  objstate IN ('Closed')
AND    actual_date_finished > Sysdate -30
AND    contract LIKE NVL('$SITE$','%')
```

Comment: The only problem is potential division by zero - otherwise +1 for this solution.